# Importing numpy

Tags: python, numpy

So I have installed numpy and imported it like this:

```
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from main.models import Operation, SendText, SendCall, LookUpNearestWorker, EnterNewWorker
from main.forms import sendText, sendCall, lookUpNearestWorker, enterNewWorker
import subprocess
import numpy
```

But I get an error saying that numpy can't be found. Can you guys help me with this one?

Comment: What's your OS? Where did you install `numpy` from? Can we see the error? We don't have crystal balls you know...

Comment: you could reinstall numpy from [here][1].


  [1]: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: I installed numpy from the binary on sourceforge. And I'm using Mac OS X

Comment: You should probably install numpy.

Comment: oh ignore that link for windows.... how do you prove you have installed numpy successfully?

Comment: @ManavDutta - What's likely happened is that you have more than one python interpreter and you've installed numpy for one, but are calling a different python interpreter when you execute your script.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses a list of directories to search for importable modules.

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

These are the directories that Python will search (in order) when it is looking for numpy. If numpy is installed correctly, it will be located in one of these directories.
How Python searches for modules is detailed [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) and sys.path [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.path)

Pip, Python's package manager, can also give us a nice list of packages that it recognizes (plus the version numbers)
You can get this list two ways: via the command line, or using the python interpreter.  Both commands will output a list of installed packages

```
$ pip freeze
```

or, in an interactive interpreter:

```
import pip
pip.get_installed_distributions()
```

If numpy appears in these lists, then python shouldn't have a problem importing it, unless numpy wasn't installed correctly.

It is possible that you might have multiple Python installations.  In that case, you need to verify that Python is searching the right paths for numpy.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
python setup.py install --prefix=/DirectoryYouWantToInstallOn/
```

and

```
export PYTHONPATH=/DirectoryYouWantToInstallOn/:$PYTHONPATH
```

on your terminal

adding

```
export PYTHONPATH=/DirectoryYouWantToInstallOn/:$PYTHONPATH
```

to your `~/.profile` file might make things lot easier.